# How to alias in Rust without explicit lifetimes?

Tags: rust, lifetime, actix-web

I need a way to make important data read-accessible, thread-safe throughout my application.

My web application in Rust with Actix-Web. Permission data is prefetched when the application starts. To be useful, the request cycle must be able to access this data and test if the current user.

Example:

```rust
#[get("/forums/{forum}/")]
pub async fn view_forum(client: ClientCtx) -> Result<impl Responder, Error> {
    if !client.can_view_forum() {
        // return error
    }
    // ...
```

The permission data is made available to the Actix-Web web server as app_data, so this might work.

```rust
#[get("/forums/{forum}/")]
pub async fn view_forum(
    client: ClientCtx,
    permissions: web::Data<PermissionData>,
) -> Result<impl Responder, Error> {
    if !permissions.can_view_forum(client) {
        // return error
    }
    // ...
```

I would like to avoid increasing the size of my route function signatures as much as possible. I will need permissions accessible everywhere the user is also accessible.

`PermissionData` is quite large and `ClientCtx`'s user data is pulled on every request. Refetching data directly to the client every request is not practical.

Actix-Web's middleware system creates these structs during the request cycle. It works in such a way that lifetimes cannot be attached to the ClientUser.

```rust
pub struct ClientCtxInner<'a> {
    pub client: Option<ClientUser>,
    pub permission: &PermissionData, // Doesn't work.
    pub request_start: Instant,
}
```

In short:

1. The user *never* needs to write to permissions. It just needs to read them.
2. Many users on all threads at all times will be reading this same data.
3. I can't use normal lifetimes.
4. I would very much prefer if the data is accessible directly through the Client struct for organization reasons.

This is where the middleware assembles the client.

```rust
    fn call(&self, req: ServiceRequest) -> Self::Future {
        let (httpreq, payload) = req.into_parts();
        let cookies = Session::extract(&httpreq).into_inner();
        let req = ServiceRequest::from_parts(httpreq, payload);
        let permissions: Option<&PermissionData> = req.app_data::<PermissionData>(); // My data!
        let ctx = ClientCtx::get_client_ctx(&mut *req.extensions_mut());
        let fut = self.service.call(req);

        async move {
            match cookies {
                Ok(cookies) => {
                    let result = authenticate_client_ctx(&cookies).await;

                    // Data needs to be attached here.
                    // ctx.0.borrow_mut().permissions = ???;

                    // Assign the user to our ClientCtx struct.
                    if let Some(user) = result {
                        ctx.0.borrow_mut().client = Some(user);
                    }
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    log::error!("ClientCtxMiddleware: Session::extract(): {}", e);
                }
            };
            let result = fut.await?;
            Ok(result)
        }
        .boxed_local()
    }
```

Comment: Two options I can think of which don't require a deep clone: wrap `PermissionData` in `std::sync::Arc` and then `clone()` it or use once_cell (https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/#lazy-initialized-global-data). I would prefer the latter as it also has less overhead (no map lookups).